# Trying to Connect Redis JSON

Tags: go, redis

I am trying to use Redis JSON in Go.
I am using go-redis for redis connection and go-rejson for JSON Handler

```
package RedisModule

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    goredis "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
    "github.com/nitishm/go-rejson"
)

var ctx = context.Background()

var Rdb goredis.Client

func ConfigureRedis() goredis.Client {
    rdb := goredis.NewClient(&goredis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })
    Rdb = *rdb
    rh := rejson.NewReJSONHandler()

    rh.SetGoRedisClient(rdb)
    return *rdb
}
```

I am getting an error `cannot use rdb (variable of type *redis.Client) as *redis.Client value in argument to rh.SetGoRedisClient compiler(IncompatibleAssign)`.

I was referring https://github.com/nitishm/go-rejson

Answer (score 1):

**Note from OP, originally included as an edit to the question**:

Change `"github.com/nitishm/go-rejson"` to  `rejson "github.com/nitishm/go-rejson/v4"`
 It will work